# Pass argument to abstract class constructor c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, oop

I have an abstract class like below:

```
Public abstract class Test
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public Test(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public ActionResult GetData()
    {
        try
        {

        }

        catch(Exception exe)

        {

            _logger.log("Exception");

        }
    }
}
```

Now, I have another class which uses the above in the below way:

```
Public class TestProcess
{
    public Test tst {get; protected set;}

    public TestProcess(Test tesstt)
    {
        tst = tesstt;
    }
}
```

Now, I want to pass the `ILogger` to my abstract constructor from `TestProcess` class. Could someone help me out how can I do this?

Comment: Note that since `TestProcess` accepts a `Test`, the `ILogger` would have already been passed to `Test` by the time the `TestProcess` constructor is called. Which `ILogger` do you want to pass anyway? I see no `ILogger` here.

Comment: May be you want to expose `internal ILogger Logger {get;}` in `Test`? Then `TestProcess` can use it

Comment: Please edit your question and add the following code (1) The class that derives from `Test` (since you cannot instantiate a `Test` directly, since it is abstract) and (2) the code that instantiates the `TestProcess` instance. Once I see that I could probably tell you how to modify it to do what you ask.

Answer (score 0):

Recommended to do following

```
Public class TestProcess:Test
{
    public ILogger _logger {get; set;}

    public TestProcess(ILogger logger): : base(logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do this and in both you need to change your code littele bit.

1. Extendes your TestProcess class with Test(abstract) class.

   public class TestProcess:Test{}
2. Change your abstract class to normal class and implement singleton there. then you can pass the ILogger while creating instance of Test class.

   public class Test{}